# How to delete the last n lines of a file?

Tags: linux, bash

I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Im writing a bash script and i want to delete the last 12 lines of a specific file.

I have had a look around and somehow come up with the following;

```
head -n -12 /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf | tee /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf >/dev/null
```

But this wipes the file completely.

All i want to do is permanently delete the last 12 lines of that file so i can overwrite it with my own rules.

Any help on where im going wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a temporary file store the intermediate result of `head -n`

I think the code below should work:

```
 head -n -12 /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf  > /tmp/tmp.pg.hba.$$ && mv /tmp/tmp.pg.hba.$$ /var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
```

If you are putting it a script, a more readable and easy to maintain code would be:

```
 SRC_FILE=/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf
 TMP_FILE=/tmp/tmp.pg.hba.$$
 head -n -12 $SRC_FILE > $TMP_FILE && mv $TMP_FILE $SRC_FILE
```

I would suggest backing up  `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_hba.conf` before running any script.

Comment: in one line: `F=/some/file; X=12; head -n -$X $F > /tmp/tmpfile && mv /tmp/tmpfile $F`

Comment: In case you're on a mac: OS X's version of `head` doesn't allow negative numbers, but you can install core-utils and use `ghead`.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of methods, depending on your exact situation.  For small, well-formed files (say, less than 1M, with regular sized lines), you might use `Vim` in `ex` mode:

```
ex -snc '$-11,$d|x' smallish_file.txt
```

- `-s` -> silent; this is batch processing, so no UI necessary (faster)
- `-n` -> No need for an undo buffer here
- `-c` -> the command list
- `'$-11,$d'` -> Select the 11 lines from the end to the end (for a total of 12 lines) and delete them.  Note the single quote so that the shell does not interpolate `$d` as a variable.
- `x` -> "write and quit"

For a similar, perhaps more authentic throw-back to '69, the `ed` line-editor could do this for you:

```
ed -s smallish_file.txt <<< $'-11,$d\nwq'
```

- Note the `$` outside of the single quote, which is different from the ex command above.

If Vim/ex and Ed are scary, you could use `sed` with some shell help:

```
sed -i "$(($(wc -l < smallish_file.txt) - 11)),\$d" smallish_file.txt
```

- `-i` -> *inplace*: write the change to the file
- The line count less 11 for a total of 12 lines.  Note the escaped dollar symbol (`$`) so the shell does not interpolate it.

But using the above methods will not be performant for larger files (say, more than a couple of megs).  For larger files, use the intermediate/temporary file method, as the other answers have described.  A `sed` approach:

```
tac some_file.txt | sed '1,12d' | tac > tmp && mv tmp some_file.txt
```

- tac to reverse the line order
- sed to remove the last (now first) 12 lines
- tac to reverse *back to* the original order

More efficient than `sed` is a `head` approach:

```
head -n -12 larger_file.txt > tmp_file && mv tmp_file larger_file.txt
```

- `-n NUM` show only the first NUM lines.  Negated as we've done, shows *up to* the last NUM lines.

But for real efficiency -- perhaps for **really** large files or for where a temporary file would be unwarranted -- truncate the file in place.  Unlike the other methods which involve variations of overwriting the *entire* old file with *entire* the new content, this one will be near instantaneous no matter the size of the file.

```
# In readable form:
BYTES=$(tail -12 really_large.txt | wc -c)
truncate -s -$BYTES really_large.txt

# Inline, perhaps as part of a script
truncate -s -$(tail -12 really_large.txt | wc -c) really_large.txt
```

The `truncate` command makes files exactly the specified size in bytes.  If the file is too short, it will make it larger, and if the file is too large, it will chop off the excess *really efficiently*.  It does this with filesystem semantics, so it involves writing usually no more than a couple of bytes.  The magic here is in calculating where to chop:

- `-s -NUM` -> Note the dash/negative; says to reduce the file by NUM bytes
- `$(tail -12 really_large.txt | wc -c)` -> returns the number of bytes to be removed

So, you pays your moneys and takes your choices.  Choose wisely!

Comment: I detect a person from my own era! Some nice insights! Can you do it in `edlin` too? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
head -n -12 test.txt > tmp.txt && cp tmp.txt test.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple and clear script

```
declare -i start
declare -i cnt
cat dummy
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
cnt=`wc -l dummy|awk '{print $1}'`
start=($cnt-12+1)
sed "${start},\$d" dummy
```

OUTPUT 
is the first line

```
1
```